# Using Javascript (DOM) with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an asp.net page with several list boxes.

I would like to include some javascript on the page that allows a user to drag individual list elements from one box to another.

On a normal web page, the script to do this is reasonably simple, however, with the element IDs generated by ASP.NET, I don't know what identifiers to have my script look up?

Any thoughts on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `ClientId` property of the `Control` class.

Note: The ASP.NET `ListBox` control inherits from `Control`.

**Update**

In reponse to the comments below, I can think of two ways to access the individual `li` elements of an unordered / ordered list generated by the `ListBox` control.

- Create a custom `Control` that inherits from
  the `ListBox` control and renders out an
  id attribute for each `li` element.
- Use the `getElementsByTagName` method
  in JavaScript. MSDN even has [an
  example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439%28VS.85%29.aspx) that uses the
  `getElementsByTagName` method to get
  the children of an unordered list and
  displays an alert indicating the
  number of children and the value of
  the first child element. If the MSDN documentation isn't your thing, you can check out the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) as well.

Comment: Thanks.  That is most helpful.  Can you, by any chance help me get an id attribute into the <li> tags so that my JS can grab an individual list item?

Answer (score 2):

Add a identifying CSS class to your elements and use those. i.e. jQuery has a superb support for that so you can grab all elements and loop through them to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the ClientId property as stated by paper1337

```
var element = document.getElementById('<%= MyDropDownList.ClientID %>');
```

or you could implement a AJAX Behavior using [AjaxControlToolkit](http://ajax.asp.net).

Code:

```
[assembly: WebResource("MyJS.js", "text/javascript")]

[ClientScriptResource("MyBehavior", "MyJS.js")]
public sealed class MyExtender : BehaviorBase {
    // can be empty
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDL" />
<my:MyExtender runat="server" TargetControl="DDL" />
```

MyJS.js (See AjaxControlToolkit samples for details):

```
...

var element = this.get_element();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on asp.net 4.0+, you can use the `ClientIDMode="Static"` to force asp.net to use the id you have specified. There's a [nice explanation on ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), and the [MSDN Docs for ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) are available.

You may also want to try `ClientIdMode="Predictable"`, if you have a lot of generated elements.